# Facebook Login Button Not Clickable

Tags: php, facebook

I am tinkering with the Facebook Login button and while it was easy to put that button on the page, when I click it, it does nothing.  Has anyone had that experience?

I had this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myRealId&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Did I need to do something extra?

You can see the button being rendered here:
http://www.comehike.com

But when you click it, it does nothing. :(

Comment: How is this security related? Anyways, my guess is that a transparent element is over it...

Comment: Security related because its login.  Its 100% security-related.  I mean...isn't login related to security? lol

Comment: Are you serious? Anyway, try to check for JavaScript errors.

Comment: In the script-url, have you replaced "myRealId" with your AppId? Because in your example you didn't!

Comment: Yes I have the real AppId in the live site - I just took it out for the sake of posting here

Comment: Could it be that you are not able to use the same AppId across 2 different sites?  I am trying to recycle an old appId that has another site regitered to it originally - might that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript Console shows me the following message:

```
FB.login() called before calling FB.init().
```

So you should probably call `FB.init()` after the button has been loaded.

Comment: So should I always have the FB.init() in the header?

Comment: Yes, but before calling the method you need to wait until the FB-Script has loaded. So you would need to trigger the function at `window.onload`.

Comment: Just did some hack like this and it didnt work:  <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myRealId&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.login();
</script>

Comment: Try adding this to your head:

    `window.onload = function () {
        FB.init();
    };`

Comment: Now I have something like this and it doesn't work lol - <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myAppId8&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
FB.init();
}

Comment: You should close the script and move it into your head.

Comment: The JS script is closed.  I just didn't paste the closing tag.  And this code is already in the header section.  Any other ideas? :)

Comment: I'm just guessing, I have no idea why this won't work. The console logs an error with one of your scripts, maybe it will help if you fix that one: `document.banner is undefined (Line 88)`